# Selecting posts that have at least one comment

Tags: mysql

Basically I want to select all the posts that have at least one comment and get the comment count for each. What I cam up with so far is only giving me one result, which is has an accurate count but there are more than one posts that have comments. Can any recommend changes to make this work

```
SELECT
    posts.id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT comments.post_id) AS count
FROM
    posts
LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.post_id
```

Comment: You don't show your code to display the results.  For all we know you might not be looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `group by` statement.  And you can change the `join` to an inner join because you want only posts with comments:

```
SELECT p.id, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM posts p INNER JOIN
     comments c
     ON p.id = c.post_id
GROUP BY p.id;
```

The expression `count(distinct c.post_id)` will return `1` for each row, because there is only one distinct post id for each row.  `COUNT(*)` will get the number of comments.

Answer (score 2):

Using aggregate functions you must group them [see here GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) for the posts must contain atleast one comment you can use `HAVING count >= 1`

```
SELECT
    posts.id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT comments.post_id) AS `count`
FROM
    posts
LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.post_id
GROUP BY posts.id
HAVING `count` >= 1
```

Comment: This works great. Is it possible to get the count values the actual count, as it is now it says 1. But the results are correct.

Comment: @road242 yup i can't change because gordon has already provided the answer using inner join

Comment: @user1715025 `count` alias will give you the original count of comments as it should